# Configurar caminhos para Produção e Homologação no servidor

Tags: php, apache, servidor

O servidor estava com a versão 5.5 do *PHP*, então precisei trocar para a 7.1. Porém após restartar o *apache*, não carrega mais o site.

Antes existia o site principal (produção) e o de testes (homologação), cada um em suas pasta dentro do "/var/www/", mas agora parece que o que fazia essa configuração de caminhos foi apagada, pois os dois estão apontando para a pasta padrão "html", como posso configurar isso de novo, já que não fui eu que configurei na primeira vez?

Comment: Viu o log de erro?

Comment: É preciso verificar o log de erro e verificar também se todos os componentes de integração entre o php e o apache estão atualizados para a versão 7.1 do php. Se eu fosse fosse, eliminava tudo do php (tudo mesmo) via terminal e instalava tudo na versão 7.1.

Comment: Me precipitei no erro, verifiquei e o php está sendo carregado. O problema é que aponta pra um arquivo html padrão do apache. Editei minha pergunta.

Comment: vc só atualizou o php ou também reinstalou o apache? será que não está faltando configurar o virtualhost?

Comment: Tu diz o arquivo 000-default.conf? Ele parece estar com as configurações padrão de quando se instalada o apache, apesar de eu não ter reinstalado o apache. Aí pensei que tinham configurado de alguma outra forma anteriormente.

Comment: Quando vc joga um arquivo php novo na raiz ele chega a ser executado? ou redireciona para o html do apache?

Comment: Configurei o virtualhost para apontar para a pasta da homologação e produção. Quando eu acesso a homologação carrega corretamente, mas a produção continua apontando pra pasta "html".

Answer (score -1):

É necessário que você configure uma `<VirtualHost>` para o servidor e homologação e outra para o servidor de produção.

O apache vem com uma configuração de `<VirtualHost>` padrão, que aponta para a pasta `/var/www/html`. Para **modificar essa configuração** padrão, acesse o arquivo `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` e crie uma nova  com a configuração do seu domínio ou IP.

Ex:

```
<VirtualHost seudomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin seuemail@email.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/seusite"
    ServerName dominio.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dominio-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dominio-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```